# r.fill.dir not working

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, error

I am using QGIS 3.16.2 "Hannover" with GRASS 7.8.4 on Windows 10 64 bits.

Im doing a watershred and r.fill.dir is not working, the message is the common `the following layers were not correctly generated`. I have an srtm of 90 meters, i did `raster- fill without data` first, so the next step is doing the `r.fill.dir` on the new `Fill` layer.

[image]

Comment: Your "Fill" layer seems to have the correct elevation range for Papua New Guinea: would you be able to share the input layer, and/or the screenshot of the `Parameters` you used?